# Is there a way to convert a Pandas Series to an element comma format?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with number in it. I'm trying to convert it into a format 1,2,3,4 so I can plug into a sql query. I've tried turning it into a list but the brackets and parenthesis cause it to error out I believe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas .to_csv method to store your data frame as a Comma Separated Values (CSV)
for more information follow this link:
[Pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()](http://pandas.DataFrame.to_csv%C2%B6)